# Weird characters from tesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-imaging-library

When I run this python code on windows 10:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
im = Image.open("news.png")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='eng')

print(text.encode("utf-8"))
```

[On this image.](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e2/1b/ee/e21bee5457751fc5aa84b62e5d72c061.png)

I get this printed:

```
    THE MN HERALD gm:-                                 
                                                   
} HEAT INVASIUN SIAHIHI                            
                                                   
Buile∩¼üns Gen. Eisenhower Bares Landings in France
                                                   
dtmmvΓÇÿ By Both Sea, Air from Le Havre North;     
                                                   
MSW \ Fierce Fight at Caen, Dunlaerque Rocked      
                                                   
EM?ΓÇ¥ 7 , w W! Paratroops Hit Nazis               
'k AWMWM In Pre-Dawn Assaults                      
                                                   
swam HEADQUARTERSΓÇÿ ALLIED EXPE                   
mmmkv poms. Im a (APIΓÇöΓÇÿAmcrfwl.                
mm m: Canadian lmvm'umlldm mum anu:                
ma mm, launrmn: m. mm: wwmmmxlfmy                  
aprn m hum mm mm mm m" supra"!                     
mummy, c". 1mm 17' 5mmΓÇ¥, m... ΓÇ£we              
m mm mm┬╗; mm mu ΓÇ£mm nun m Gar                   
man mmlm n┬╗ m: can                                
                                                   
u. mm, which                                       
mm" m nnmmntl                                      
(mum                                               
(ammunlaur N. 1;                                   
r m: cwmand 07 Cm. Elunhown MM                     
m: Yam: :unpurltd by gm, m┬╗ Mm. mm.               
(mm, Mind mm m, mm. m m mum                        
┬╗ man ┬½2mm                                       
                                                
.m and ΓÇ£a [um                                    
72 A M. Cvunmfch                                   
mwmnmummmn.ΓÇÖ
```

Any ideas why I am getting this weird output, is this a limitation with tesseract or am I been dumb?

Thanks, Ed.

Comment: That's a pretty crappy-quality image. I wouldn't expect much out of the OCR to be anything other than junk.

Comment: Did the unicode version of `text` actually contain all the same characters you're seeing in the output? I'm not sure why the `encode` call is necessary. Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Have to call encode to avoid an error, not sure how to check the python type but it looks like it is just a hard to read image.